# How can I fix an incorrect SQL field in Recurring Contribution View?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, recurring-contributions, civicrm-entity

I'm trying to create a view that will tell our logged-in Drupal users when their next scheduled contribution is slated to happen.  Everything is working well until I add the field "CiviCRM Recurring Contributions: Next Contribution Date".  When that happens, my preview gives the error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
> 'civicrm_contribution_recur.next_sched_contribution' in 'field list'

The Views SQL query shows this field being called:

```
civicrm_contribution_recur.next_sched_contribution AS civicrm_contribution_recur_next_sched_contribution
```

That is the correct table, but the field name is incorrect.  It should be `next_sched_contribution_date`.  I've tried searching in the [CiviCRM Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) [Github repo](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/civicrm_entity), but I can't find where the (incorrect) field name is being generated.  Where would I look to find the error?  Or am I looking in the wrong place entirely and it's not a CiviCRM Entity issue at all?  I want to help, I just don't know where to correct it.

We're using Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.6.21, CiviCRM Entity module 7.x-2.0-beta3.  The type of view is "CiviCRM Recurring Contribution profile."

Comment: Hi Allen - I am not clear. Are using the civicrm_entity module. if so is your view built on the standard 'contribution' or on the entity contribution base

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks for asking and helping me remember what I forgot to post. :) I've updated the question.  Yes on the CiviCRM-Entity module.  Using the view type of "CiviCRM Recurring Contribution profile", not the "CiviCRM Recurring Entity."

Comment: In the future, the best place to get support for CiviCRM Entity is via the module's issue queue, https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/civicrm_entity?status=All&categories=All

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this - got it working - (4.6 line numbers) - just need to update the field names (see below). After applying the patch clear caches (the views cache in particular).

I do not have CiviCRM Entity installed for this project - this is a straight up CiviCRM Views integration/fix.

```
diff --git a/drupal/modules/views/components/civicrm.contribute.inc b/drupal/modules/views/components/civicrm.contribute.inc
index e666a45..1b4a20f 100644
--- a/drupal/modules/views/components/civicrm.contribute.inc
+++ b/drupal/modules/views/components/civicrm.contribute.inc
@@ -1023,7 +1023,7 @@ function _civicrm_contribute_data(&$data, $enabled) {
     ),
   );
   //Recurring Contribution End Date
-  $data['civicrm_contribution_recur']['next_sched_contribution'] = array(
+  $data['civicrm_contribution_recur']['next_sched_contribution_date'] = array(
     'title' => t('Next Contribution Date'),
     'help' => t('The Next Contribution Date.'),
     'field' => array(
@@ -1040,7 +1040,7 @@ function _civicrm_contribute_data(&$data, $enabled) {
   );
   civicrm_views_add_date_arguments($data['civicrm_contribution_recur'], array(
     'title' => 'Recurring Contribution Next Date',
-      'name' => 'next_sched_contribution',
+      'name' => 'next_sched_contribution_date',
     ));
   //How many times has the contribution failed
   $data['civicrm_contribution_recur']['failure_count'] = array(
```

Answer (score 2):

That particular table is exposed to Views by the Core CiviCRM module, not CiviCRM entity.  I haven't exposed that entity to Drupal yet, but its on the todo list.

I have added some code to CiviCRM Entity to fix this...

Its available in the latest -dev release from the [CiviCRM Entity project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity)
and will be in beta7 when it is released